# How to grant all camera permission for chrome driver in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I am a beginner in selenium, one part of my testing is to open a page and click a picture using the camera, but while automating in chrome driver every time a pop up occurs asking "to allow permission".How to automate it, how to grant all the permission at initialization of the driver itself?

Comment: This is a totally valid question since camera permissions launch an OS level dialog that is not obviously accessible via Selenium.  It appears OP can use Chrome profile, if he is running locally but its unclear what a solution is for the RemoteDriver case.